# How do I check whether a file type is supported by `MediaPlayer` audio playback?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a `File` that may be an audio file or not. How can I test programmatically whether it actually is an audio file, that can be played using `MediaPlayer`?

There's [a list of supported types](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#audio-formats) available online, but it would involve lots of hard-coded constants and version checks to use that. There must be an API for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest checking for the mime type as below

```
File file = new File(path, name);

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
int index = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.')+1;
String ext = file.getName().substring(index).toLowerCase();
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
try
{
  context.startActivity(intent);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: This would help a little bit, but the problem is not really, how I get the type, but rather how to get the supported _audio_ file types of `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: well i would suggets including all supported types in a hashmap Hashmap<String, String> or a List and then compare your extracted type with it...

Comment: As I said, the supported types differ from version to version.

Comment: But of course you're right, if there's no special API, I would have to do that.